# problem with array format when upload multiple images with retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I have problem when upload multiple images file using retrofit

First i use `ArrayList` with `MultipartBody` like this

```
val list : MutableList<MultipartBody.Part> = arrayListOf()
for(c in uris!!){
    val file : File? = File(getRealPathFromUri(applicationContext,c))

    if(file != null){
        val requestFile = file.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        val body : MultipartBody.Part  = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("files", file.name, requestFile)
        list.add(body)
    }
}
```

route interface

```
@Multipart
@POST("meme-upload")
fun postMeme(
   @Part files: List<MultipartBody.Part>?
): Call<ResponseBody>?
```

but i only got last image, and i change 'files' to 'files[]' like this

```
    val requestFile = file.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
    val body : MultipartBody.Part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("files[]", file.name, requestFile)
    list.add(body)
```

The server gets an array of data but the format is not correct

expected array

```
files [
  path_1,
  path_2,
  path_3
]
```

array received

```
files [
  [
    path_1,
    path_2,
    path_3
  ]
]
```

I also use `RequestBody` and `MultipartBody.Builder` but got same result

**UPDATE**

oh sorry after coordinating with the server it turns out it's just a problem with naming the key

Answer (score 0):

oh sorry after coordinating with the server it turns out it's just a problem with naming the key